# Optimizing query to show repeat customer

Tags: mysql, prestashop, sqlperformance

I am working with prestashop 1.5 and have the following query that shows repeat customer (previous year vs next year).

```
SELECT prev.id_customer, prev.name, prev.email, prev.count AS 'prev', next.count AS 'next'
FROM(
    SELECT o.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, c.email, COUNT(1) AS 'count'
    FROM ps_orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN ps_order_history AS h ON o.id_order = h.id_order
    LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c on o.id_customer = c.id_customer
    WHERE o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
    AND h.id_order_state = 2
    GROUP BY o.id_customer
    ORDER BY count DESC
) AS prev,
(
    SELECT o.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, c.email, COUNT(1) AS 'count'
    FROM ps_orders AS o
    LEFT JOIN ps_order_history AS h ON o.id_order = h.id_order
    LEFT JOIN ps_customer AS c on o.id_customer = c.id_customer
    WHERE o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
    AND h.id_order_state = 2
    GROUP BY o.id_customer
    ORDER BY count DESC
) AS next
WHERE prev.id_customer = next.id_customer
ORDER BY prev.name ASC;
```

I would like to know whether there is better way to optimize this query ? I am thinking of creating a VIEW for each year thus minimizing the number of lines. But i am not sure whether it is better (performance wise).

Can anyone give me a better solution to this?

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.id_customer, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, c.email, 
       SUM(o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31') as cnt_2014,
       SUM(o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31') as cnt_2015
FROM ps_orders o LEFT JOIN
     ps_order_history h
     ON o.id_order = h.id_order LEFT JOIN
     ps_customer c
     on o.id_customer = c.id_customer
WHERE h.id_order_state = 2
GROUP BY o.id_customer;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that queries also includes non-repeat customer (i.e. Cust X made transaction in 2013, but not in 2014). Unless of course if i treat your query as a nested select and add Where clause (e.g WHERE cnt_2014 > 0 AND cnt_2015 > 0).

Comment: You can just add `and o.invoice_date between '2014-01-01' and '2015-12-31'`.

Comment: Sorry, it still does not return the right result (or perhaps i am missing something here). See my edit.

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan . . . I don't know what is wrong with the result.  If you only want customers with purchases in both years, you can always add `having cnt_2014 > 0 and cnt_2015 > 0`.